# Acceptable USB chips for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, usb, drivers, hardware-rec

With Apple's push to the App Store for Mac OS X applications, and the fact that you are not allowed to install drivers in the OS to be in the Store we are left with a hardware quandary.

Investigating USB chips for a piece of hardware we found a good chip and then discovered that it had it's own USB driver and that driver only was supported 10.5.8 (ppc/i386).

*Is there a good reference for USB chips that are natively supported by the OS* so that going forwards we wouldn't have to supply a driver as it would already be built in?

I'd hate to think that as I go shopping for USB chips the first thing I have to do is extract driver support for each one. It'd seem to make sense that there be a list already of approved chips.

**Edit**: For clarifiction. I am building a USB *thingee* to use with the Mac and am shopping for USB chips for the circuits. I need to know that when I hook my USB device to the Mac that I'm not going to be in Driver hell or installer hell blocking me from the App Store.

Comment: Do not cross post like that, Stack Overflow will migrate it for you next time

Comment: @SimonSheehan Thank you, I was unaware of that.

Comment: It's not your fault, it's just others failing to explain to you what should be done in such a situation.

Comment: @slhck Ok, noted. I don't know there is auto migrated feature. Sorry.

Comment: I suggest finding a website that has taken apart say a Macbook Pro or do it yourself all that information should be on the chip.  I don't understand the connection to the OS X Application Store and USB Controller Chip....

Comment: Can you find something which pretends to be a generic device? Maybe a HID or a serial?